# ansible - run tests for specific module/package (from source)

Tags: python, unit-testing, ansible, tox

So I cloned ansible repository and had setup it with venv. And I want to run  specific modules/packages unittests (it does run unittests fully, if I do not specify any pattern or specify specific file).

I tried these variants (first two do not work):

First:

```
source venv/bin/activate && source hacking/env-setup && ansible-test units --tox --python 3.6 google

ERROR: Target pattern not matched: google
```

Second:

```
source venv/bin/activate && source hacking/env-setup && ansible-test units --tox --python 3.6 cloud

ERROR: Target pattern not matched: cloud
```

Third:

```
source venv/bin/activate && source hacking/env-setup && ansible-test units --tox --python 3.6 test/units/modules/cloud/google/test_gce_tag.py

...
- generated xml file: /home/oerp/src/ansible/test/results/junit/python3.6-units.xml -
============================== 3 passed in 1.68s ===============================
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
  py36: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

There is an example in documentation, showing how to run tests for specific file:
`ansible-test units --tox --python 2.7 apt`

Maybe I understand that sample incorrectly? Or how should I run unittests for packages as `google` or whole group, `cloud`?

Update. Also tried `test/units/modules/cloud/google`, but getting same ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the gce_tag module, all you need to do is to specify that as the target, because there is a test_gce_tag.py file in the appropriate place under test/units.

```
source venv/bin/activate
source hacking/env-setup
ansible-test units --tox --python 2.7 gce_tag
```

If you want to test all of cloud/google, your third example is the way to go, with a full path and a wildcard character that your shell will expand for you:

```
ansible-test units --tox --python 2.7 test/units/modules/cloud/google/test*.py
```